# What is the best way in linq to calculate the percentage from a list?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of 1s and 0s and I have to now calculate the percent meaning if 1 he achieved it else he doesn't. So e.g  -

```
{1,1,0,0,0}
```

So for e.g If List has 5 items and he got 2 ones then his percent is 40%. Is there a function or way in LINQ I could do it easily maybe in one line ? I am sure LINQ experts have a suave way of doing it ?

Comment: you mean "If List has 5 *elements* and he got 2 ones ...", I assume...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What about

```
var list = new List<int>{1,1,0,0,0};
var percentage = ((double)list.Sum())/list.Count*100;
```

or if you want to get the percentage of a specific element

```
var percentage = ((double)list.Count(i=>i==1))/list.Count*100;
```

**EDIT**

Note BrokenGlass's solution and use the `Average` extension method for the first case as in

```
var percentage = list.Average() * 100;
```

Comment: Cool..Thanks for the `percentage of a specific element` it might come in useful.

Answer (score 6):

If you're working with any `ICollection<T>` (such as `List<T>`) the `Count` property will *probably* be O(1); but in the more general case of *any* sequence the `Count()` extension method is going to be O(N), making it less than ideal. Thus for the most general case you might consider something like this which counts elements matching a specified predicate *and* all elements in one go:

```
public static double Percent<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    int total = 0;
    int count = 0;

    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        ++count;
        if (predicate(item))
        {
            total += 1;
        }
    }

    return (100.0 * total) / count;
}
```

Then you'd just do:

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 };
double percent = list.Percent(i => i == 1);
```

Output:

```
40
```

Comment: Please note that in the Linq-World, *every* collection supplies a `Count` (extension) method. And since the question was for a Linq-Solution, the `Count(predicate)` supplies the other half of your loop.

Comment: @MartinStettner: In the LINQ world, any sequence *can be counted* using the `Count` extension method, yes; but if you call `Sum` and divide by `Count` (or `Count(predicate)` divided by `Count`) then you will be iterating over the sequence twice, doing redundant work.

Comment: That's correct, of course. On the other hand programming Linq is mostly about combining existing functions *instead* of writing custom `foreach` loops for every problem. And the question was specifically about a Linq solution. But I got your point (and noticed the extension method which I overread the first time and which is also considered "Linquish" in some way) and undid my downvote :)

Comment: If you're not careful, programming Linq can result in some very suboptimal performance. This extension method solves a rather common problem, not a tightly defined one, and is a good addition to a programmer's toolkit.

Answer (score 6):

In this special case you can also use `Average()` :

```
var list = new List<int> {1,1,0,0,0};
double percent = list.Average() * 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do it:

```
var percentage = ((double)list.Count(i=>i==1))/list.Count*100;
```

or

```
var percentage = ((double)list.Count(i=>i <= yourValueHere))/list.Count*100;
```

Answer (score 0):

**If You**

- want to do it in one line
- don't want to maintain an extension method
- can't take advantage of `list.Sum()` because your list data isn't 1s and 0s

you can do something like this:

```cs
percentAchieved = (int)
                  ((double)(from MyClass myClass
                  in myList
                  where MyClass.SomeProperty == "SomeValue"
                  select myClass).ToList().Count / 
                  (double)myList.Count * 
                  100.0
                  );
```